# Java Replace a particular character

Tags: java, regex

The following regex

```
str = str.replace(/,/g, '');
```

works well in javascript to replace any particular character(comma in this case).How to achieve same in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str = str.replaceAll(",", "");
```

Replaces every comma with nothing